# Express, calling then() function second times, return undefined object after saving an object with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, promise

I want to sending data to nats streaming server with publisher function. For that I need a second then then function on mongoose model save. But when I call second times then() function,
`then(result => {})`  result is return as undefined.

```
todo.save().then(result =>{
   console.log(result)
   res.status(201).json({
       message : "done",
       todo : result
   });
}).then(result =>{
       console.log(result); // ===> this return undefined
       //natsPublisher(result.title, result.context); ===> I want to send this info to nats streaming
})
.catch(err=>{
   console.log(err);
   res.status(500).json({
       message : "There is an error"
   })
})
```

How can I solve this problem? Maybe my structure is very bad. If it is very bad please say to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `result` from the callback function of the first `then()` method.

```
todo.save()
 .then(result => {
    ...
    return result;      
 })
 .then(result =>{
    // access result
 })
```

Each `then()` method call returns a `Promise` and that `Promise` is either fulfilled or rejected depending on what you return from the callback function of that particular `then()` method.

If you return a non-promise value from the callback function, the `Promise` returned by the wrapper `then()` method will get fulfilled with that value and that fulfilled value will be passed as an argument to the callback function of the next `then()` method, if it exists.

If you return a `Promise` from the callback function of the `then()` method, then the `Promise` returned by that `then()` method will get *resolved* to the `Promise` returned by its callback function. This means that `Promise` returned by the `then()` method will either get fulfilled or rejected depending on what happens to the `Promise` returned by its callback function.

If the `Promise` returned by the callback function is fulfilled with a non-promise value, the `Promise` returned by the `then()` method gets fulfilled with that same value and this value is passed as an argument to the callback function of the next `then()` method, if it exists.

> Maybe my structure is very bad. If it is very bad please say to me.

I don't see why you need the second `then()` method. You can just pass the data to the `natsPublisher()` function in the callback function of the first `then()` method.